# Package fails to build install when `rjags` is in Depends

Tags: r

I've been working on updating my `HydeNet` package for CRAN.  After making changes to the code, I ran `devtools::install_local('HydeNet')` and received the following:

```
** testing if installed package can be loaded
*** arch - i386
*** arch - x64
ERROR: loading failed for 'i386'
```

In the process, get a dialog window that says

[image]

I spent several hours this  morning reinstalling R, reinstalling Rtools, reinstalling RStudio, double checking environment variables.  Finally, I decided to simply remove all of the content from the package and start with just the DESCRIPTION and NAMESPACE.  I intended to add one function at a time until I figured out where the problem was.

To my surprise, with only the DESCRIPTION file, I got the same result.  So I started removing dependencies.  I eventually narrowed it down to the `rjags` package being in the `Depends:` section.

I now have all of my content back in my package.  Everything works great when I put `rjags` in `Imports:` (package builds, installs, vignettes run, examples run, all tests pass, check finds no problems [a]).  But if I put `rjags` into `Depends:`, it fails to install.

It isn't crucial that I have `rjags` in `Depends:`, but would be convenient as it is conceivable that someone would use `rjags` functions with this package.  Any ideas on why it fails with `rjags` in `Depends:`, but not in `Imports:`?

[a]: well, I get a note about undocumented arguments, for `%>%`, but I doubt that's related.